# the conjugate of a supercritical branching process is subcritical

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\mu$ denote the extinction probability of a branching process $X$, with offspring distribution $(p_k)_{k\geq0}$. The conjugate distribution $p^\prime$ of $p$, is defined as

\begin{equation}p_k^\prime=\mu^{k-1}p_k
\end{equation}
Let $X'$ be a random variable with the conjugate distribution $p_k'$.

**Show that, $\mu<1\Rightarrow E[X']<1$**

What I have tried is as follow:

We know that $\mu<1\Longleftrightarrow E[X]>1\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp_k>1$

and, $\mu=G_X(\mu)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p_k\mu^k<1$

What need to be proved is $E(X')=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp'_k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\mu^{k-1}p_k<1$.

I have tried some transformations, but nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $E(X')=\sum_{k\geq1}k\mu^{k-1}p_k=\sum_{k\geq1}\dfrac{d}{d\mu}(\mu^kp_k)=\dfrac{d}{d\mu}\sum_{k\geq1}\mu^kp_k=\dfrac{d}{d\mu}\sum_{k\geq0}\mu^kp_k=\dfrac{d}{d\mu}G(\mu)=\dfrac{d}{d\mu}\mu=1$

So I don't see why $E(X')<1$. Interchange of differentiation and summation is justified by the fact that $\mu<1$ so $\sum_k\mu^kp_k\leq\sum_k\mu^k$ which is finite.